# Create an ember component for input validation

Tags: javascript, validation, ember.js

I have a form in an Ember app which is starting to get a bit ugly after adding in server side validation feedback and I have tried to convert it into a component using [This link](http://alexspeller.com/server-side-validations-with-ember-data-and-ds-errors/) as a base

My current input box looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="group-label">Message:</label>
  {{textarea value=model.message classNames="group-control" placeholder="Message"}}
</div>
<div {{bind-attr class=":form-group model.errors.message:has-error"}}>
  <label class="group-label">Message:</label>
  {{input value=model.message classNames="group-control" placeholder="Message"}}
</div>
{{#if model.errors.message}}
  <div class="group-errors">
    {{#each error in model.errors.message}}
      <div class="error">
        {{error.message}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

I would like to convert that into a component, this is what I currently have:

`form-input.hbs`

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":form-group hasError:has-error"}}>
  <label class="group-label" {{bind-attr for=label}}>{{label}}</label>
  {{yield}}
</div>
{{#if errors.length}}
  <p>Errors</p>
  <span class="help-block">
    {{errors}}
  </span>
{{/if}}
```

`form-input_component.coffee`

```
App.FormInputComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  label: Em.computed 'for', ->
    @get('for').underscore().replace(/_/g, " ").capitalize()

  hasError: (->
    @get('object.errors')?.has @get('for')
  ).property 'object.errors.[]'

  errors: (->
    return Ember.A() unless @get('object.errors')
    @get('object.errors').errorsFor(@get('for')).mapBy('message').join(', ')
  ).property 'object.errors.[]'
```

This displays the input field correctly but the errors do not display, I am missing something but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of what the api returns back as errors? That influences how ember-data actually injects the errors into the model

Comment: I am running on a rails backend, my initial input snippet displays the errors perfectly, they just dont seem to appear in the component.